# Sulu: Including custom entity in admin search

Tags: sulu

While evaluating Sulu (read: I’m a Sulu newbie), I added a custom entity. In the entity’s list XML configuration I used `searchability="yes"` on some properties, which works for defining which properties are used for filtering the list of entities.

But (other than I would have expected) this attribute does not have any effect on the global admin search. So my question ist: how can I achieve that my custom entities are found in the global Sulu admin search?

I did not find any information on this in the cookbook nor in the sulu-demo repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already noticed, the properties in the list configuration are used only for displaying the list in the administration interface. The list configuration is separated from the global search functionality.

The search functionality of the administration interface is implemented by the `SuluSearchBundle`. It builds upon another bundle called the `MassiveSearchBundle`. If you want to integrate your custom entity with the global search functionality, you need to do two things:

1. Configure the `MassiveSearchBundle` to index the data of your custom entity. The [`MassiveSearchBundle` documentation](https://massivesearchbundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) should explain how to do this.
2. Register the index in the `SuluSearchBundle` to make it searchable via the administration interface. This step is described in the [Sulu documentation](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/bundles/search.html).

Comment: Assuming that you are the Sulu core member by the same name I have no doubts you know what you are talking about and therefore accepted the answer. Despite that, I found the answer very discouraging. Sulu alread has quite some admin config for the entity (incl. list filtering), but forces me to do more config. This was the reason why I asked in the first place: because I thought I must have missed something and that Sulu did this (semi-)automatically, at least for admin.